# Can't create valid reference to class library

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reference, assemblies

**IMPORTANT! I was confusing myself, being in another project/assembly than I expected. Things work ok, when I'm in the right place. Thanks for all help anyway, spend no more time on this one!**

I have an MVC3 project, which uses an ClassLibrary-assembly. I would like to create instances from types in that class library from a console application (in the same solution).

I have made sure that I use the fully qualified name, since it's a different assembly than the console app. In my case, the type name is:

```
KIBS.DykrapportDomain.Model.DykRapport_Utrustning, DykrapportDomain, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

I've added a reference to the class library project from the console project, it seems fine when I open it in the Object Browser, I can see everything inside. I have also made sure that the target framework is .NET 4 (not client profile) for either of the projects.

Still, when I add the following statement:

```
using KIBS.DykrapportDomain.Model;
```

I get an **The type or namespace name 'KIBS' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

What am I missing!?

Comment: Are you checked if KIBS has dependencies of other assembly?

Comment: KIBS does have a few dependencies, do I have to add those to the console app also?

Comment: Has the KIBS project been built? is there a DLL in the debug directory? might seem obvious but it has happened to me where I "Clean" a project and try to re-build a solution. VS tries to build dependent before dependency and I get a missing namespace error.

Comment: Another thing to look for: is the DykRapport_Utrustnin public? is there any public types in that namespace?

Comment: Yes, all classes are public (are EF-classes), and the DykrapportDomain.dll is in the bin/debug of the console app (and in the /bin for the web app).

Answer (score 1):

Check your console application and make sure it targets the full .Net framework and not the the client Profile version.

Comment: Beat me to it, usually something like this.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that, both have the full .NET 4.

Answer (score 0):

Check the name space of the class which you want to create the inside the console application  and if KIBS.DykrapportDomain.Model then it should work other wise use the namespace that is inside the class